# jmockit / easymock verify not-mocked method was called i.e. verify it is called without changing its behaviour

Tags: junit4, easymock, jmockit

The case is for the integration test, where we want the behavior to be intact and just want to verify if it was called or not.

The method which I want to verify does not belong to my current test class; So I don't have an instance of it accessible/injectable.

I tried for Verifications and Expectations but those are mocking the method.

Comment: You should verify the expected outcome in a proper way, instead of checking a method was called. Anyway, with JMockit it can be done (although I don't recommend it) by partially mocking the class having the method to be verified, and then using a verification block.

Answer (score 0):

A code example would be useful but I think I got what you want to do. With EasyMock, you need a mock that delegates to the real implementation.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyTest {

  public static class MockedClass {
    public int value() {
      return 12;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MockedClass realClass = new MockedClass();
    MockedClass mock = createMock(MockedClass.class);

    expect(mock.value()).andDelegateTo(realClass);

    replay(mock);

    // The test
    mock.value();

    // The verification
    verify(mock);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will add an example shortly. The above answer is in sync with what I asked. But, I have a bit more complication, the method which I want to verify does not belong to my current test class; So I don't have an instance of it accessible/injectable. So, Could you please suggest if something you already have an answer for this.